# How to use Exposed Filter criteria form for Advanced forum

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm trying to modify my *Advanced forum topic list* Master view to have an exposed filter so that my users can search for topics.

However, after even a clean install with simplytest.me gives me the same problem: while entering a search query into the exposed form, the user will be redirected to the front page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but might help toward writing one.

I found that the redirected page url had appended something like this:

?sid[]=6

which, when I appended to the forum page url, worked as desired - filtering as desired. So the url is created without the forum page part, just appending the above to the main site url part.

Comment: I found I did not have AJAX enabled for my view-  when I enabled AJAX, then the redirect to the home page quit, and the exposed filter worked normally.